# If $u^2(z) + v^2(z) \neq 1$ then $u, v$ has to be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f = u + iv$ be holomorphic function where $u, v$ are real valued functions satistying $u^2(z) + v^2(z) \neq 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$. I want to prove that $u, v$ have to be constant.

**My work so far**

Since $f$ is holomorphic, then:

$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dy} \Rightarrow u = \int \frac{dv}{dy} dx$$

and

$$-\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{dv}{dx} \Rightarrow v = -\int\frac{du}{dy}dx$$

Connecting these facts we have that:

$$(\int \frac{dv}{dy} dx)^2 + (\int\frac{du}{dy} dx)^2 \neq 1$$

But not I'm stucked, I'm not sure how out of that fact we can have that $u$ or $v$ has to be constant. Could you please give a hand in this problem?

**EDIT**

Thank you very much for your answer! My attempt of application of Liouville's theorem was the following:

Since $\textrm{Image}(f) \subset D \cup E$ we know that $\textrm{Image}(f) \subset D$ or $\textrm{Image}(f) \subset E$

What we want to show is that there exists $M$ such that $|f(z)| \le M$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$. If we take $\textrm{Image}(f) \subset D$ we will have that $$|f(z)| \le \textrm{sup}D$$ so out of this fact we know that it's bounded and hence its constant.

But I have one doubt concerning my solution. Can I simply extend the result to $\textrm{Image}(f) \subset E$? And is it true that $\textrm{sup}D \in \mathbb{R}$?

**By Little Picard's theorem**

Little Picard's theorem says that:

> If a function f : C → C is entire and non-constant, then the set of
> values that f(z) assumes is either the whole complex plane or the
> plane minus a single point.

So if we assume that $f$ is not constant then Image$f$ should be either whole $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb C \ {z_0}$, but its not true since $\{z \in \mathbb C: u^2(z) + v^2(z) = 1\}$ does not belong to it. So $f$ has to be constant and hence, $u$ and $v$ have to be constant.

Answer (score 3):

Let $D=\{z\in\Bbb{C}\,:\,|z|<1\}$ and let $E=\{z\in\Bbb{C}\,:\, |z|>1\}$ be the unit disc, and the exterior of the unit disc.

You have a holomorphic function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ such that the image of $f$ does not intersect the unit circle $S^1$, i.e $\text{image}(f)\subset D\cup E$. Now, by connectedness of $\Bbb{C}$, and continuity of $f$, what can you conclude?

Imagine that $\text{image}(f)\subset D$. There's a very famous theorem of Liouville which can be applied here. If $\text{image}(f)\subset E$, the same theorem can be applied to a slightly different function (which one?). Hence...

Comment: or if you want to be an absolute savage... you can also invoke [Little Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem).

Comment: Picards theorem is surely an overkill for this almost trivial question.  @peek-a-boo

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy completely agree, which is why I left it as a comment, mainly as a joke (and also as a fun theorem for OP to be aware of)

Comment: I eddited my question. Could you please have a look at it? Is my justification with Liouville's theorem and Little Picard Theorem correct?

Comment: @Lucian why does $\text{image}(f)\subset D\cup E$ imply $\text{image}(f)\subset D$ or $\text{image}(f)\subset E$? (It is NOT by definition of $\cup$). Also what do you mean by $\sup D$? $D$ is not a set of real numbers, so you can't take supremum. I think you have the right idea, but you're just not saying it correctly. Say in words what $D$ is. Therefore, if $\text{image}(f)\subset D$, then what is an obvious upper bound of $|f|$? In the other case, consider $1/f$.

Comment: Regarding your use of Little Picard, yes it is almost right. You probably meant $S^1=\{z\,:\, |z|=1\}$ is not part of the image (but as I mentioned in one of my previous comments, the Little Picard reference was mainly as a joke/ fun-fact to keep in mind, because Little Picard is a rather difficult theorem to prove, so we shouldn't really be using such nuclear warhammers to answer simple questions).

Comment: Would it be true if I say that $\textrm{Image}(f)$ is bounded by $S^1$, when Image$(f) \subset D$. And on the another hand (Image$(f) \subset E$) we have exactly the same bound for function $\frac 1 f$?

Comment: yes, $f$ is bounded by $1$ in the first case and $\frac{1}{f}$ is bounded by $1$ in the second case.